# FPSAnimation not updating based on time

Tags: java, animation, jogl

I'm trying to learn JOGL, and am following the tutorial here: https://sites.google.com/site/justinscsstuff/jogl-tutorial-3.  Everything seems to work up until the end, where the FPSAnimation object does not seem to be calling update.  Update is called when I'm resizing the screen, but it is not being called every 10th of a second as I would expect.  I did have to make some adjustments to the tutorial example (Java was complaining it could not cast FPSAnimation into Animation for some reason).   I have the modified code here:

```
public class SimpleScene implements GLEventListener {
    private double x = -1;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GLProfile glp = GLProfile.getDefault();
        GLCapabilities caps = new GLCapabilities(glp);
        GLCanvas canvas = new GLCanvas(caps);

        Frame frame = new Frame("Test");
        frame.setSize(300, 300);
        frame.add(canvas);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });

        canvas.addGLEventListener(new SimpleScene());

        FPSAnimator animator = new FPSAnimator(canvas, 10);
        animator.add(canvas);
        animator.start();
    }

    public void display(GLAutoDrawable drawable) {
        update();
        render(drawable);
    }
    public void dispose(GLAutoDrawable drawable) {}
    public void init(GLAutoDrawable drawable) {}
    public void reshape(GLAutoDrawable drawable, int x, int y, int w, int h) {}

    private void update() {    x += 0.01;   }

    private void render(GLAutoDrawable drawable) {
        GL2 gl = drawable.getGL().getGL2();
        gl.glBegin(GL.GL_TRIANGLES);
        gl.glClear(GL.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT); gl.glColor3f(1, 1, 1);
        gl.glVertex2d(-1, -1);  gl.glVertex2d(x, 1);  gl.glVertex2d(1, -1);
        gl.glEnd();
    }
}
```

I'm running on Windows32:

```
C:\Users\John>java -version
java version "1.7.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_45-b18)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.45-b08, mixed mode)
```

I've looked online and can't seem to find any references to this issue.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `animator.add(canvas);` is unnecessary.

Comment: Thanks, I removed that line, and everything started to work...   I guess adding the canvas overwrites the fps setting somehow.

Comment: You already pass the canvas to the animator, Svetlin is right.